# How can I print numbers within given range in random order

Tags: java, random, numbers

How can I print numbers in given range. Example: 10 - 13 in randomized order (10 12 13 11)?

```
public class RandomizeNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int minimum = getInput.nextInt();
        int maximum = getInput.nextInt();
        Random t = new Random();

        for (int i = minimum; i <= maximum; i++) {
            System.out.println(t.nextInt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: @SajanChandran No, it is not a duplicate. The current question is about list permutations. Your link is about picking one random integer in a specific range.

Answer (score 4):

Fill up a list with necessary items and shuffle them using `Collections.shuffle()`, then print:

```
List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
   c.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(c);
System.out.println(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for knowledge, you must not use this approach,

```
new Random().ints(start, endExclusive).distinct().limit(quantity).boxed().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Obs: you need java 8 to use it.

Comment: for large range of numbers it is very inefficient (more items generated -> more attempts to generate next one).

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yes, it's very inefficient. At the point of performance, probably your solution is one of the best available.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), it is as simple as:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(minimum, maximum).map(i -> t.nextInt(i))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Usage:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class RandomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int minimum = getInput.nextInt();
        int maximum = getInput.nextInt();

        Random t = new Random();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(minimum, maximum).map(i -> t.nextInt(i))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        getInput.close();
    }
}
```